# Executar aquivo php com javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ola preciso executar uma pagina php, so quero enviar o id par apoder executar uma função basica la mas n estou conseguinte fazer isso com javascript.

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function removemen(id){ 

load('functions/atumensainbox.php?id_del=' + id );

}; 

</script>
```

```html
<div class="title" onclick="passar(2);" ><b>Pasando id por click</b></div>


Pego o id e executo uma função depois pelo por _REQUEST
<?php

$id_dels=$_REQUEST['id_del'];

?>
```

desde ja grato

Comment: Troca `load(...)` por `$.get(...)`.

Comment: Obrigado amigo tinha esquecido do get lembrei que o load era para mim pegar algo da pagina e imprimir em outra etc valew mesmo obrigado

Comment: Foi um prazer ter ajudado, Gezer! @AnthonyAccioly, postei uma resposta mais elaborada. Obrigado ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Por que não está funcionando?

No trecho onde você está usando o `load(url)`, imagino que você espera que ele acesse a `url` que forneceu e quando a execução chegar até lá você termina de resolver as coisas. No entanto, `load(...)` no seu código faz com que o `javascript` entenda que existe uma função chamada `load`, tal como `function load(url){...}` criada ou importada por você em algum momento. Em `jQuery` o correto seria usar a função `$.load()`[[+]](http://api.jquery.com/load/) atribuida a algum elemento no seu `HTML`, por exemplo: `$("body").load(url)`. Veja que a aqui a declaração é diferente da forma que tentou na sua primeira tentativa.

### Eis a solução

O `jQuery` fornece a função `$.get`[[+]](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) e `$.post`[[+]](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), que nada mais são do que atalhos para a `$.ajax(...)`[[+]](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) que permite que você execute o acesso a uma `url` pelo seu código `javascript`. Essa função é exclusiva do `jQuery`, que pode ser baixado por [aqui](http://jquery.com/download/).

Se testar, vai ver que o `$.load` funciona igual o `$.get`. A documentação do `jQuery` explica como utilizar as duas formas. `$.load` é atribuída a algum elemento na estrutura que vai receber a resposta da execução da `url`, `$.get` vai depender de com você vai querer tratar a resposta da execução da `url`.

A implementação no seu código será:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function removemen(id)
{
    var url = 'functions/atumensainbox.php?id_del=' + id;
    $.get(url, function(retorno){
        /* aqui o tratamento de alguma retorno que o final da execução da sua url fornece*/
    });
}; 
</script>
```

Se não houver retorno da execução da sua `url`, o trecho `, function(retorno){}` não precisa ser emitido.

Comment: William, achei bem explicativo me clareou bem , agora fiquei com uma dúvida (sou iniciante de js) : A função "load()", é então um método exclusivo ao Jq, e no puro js ela seria idêntica a uma função "function abra()", essa parte que estou confuso ?

Comment: @MagicHat sim, você está certo quanto as funções no `javascript` :) Quanto ao `jQuery` eu editei a resposta para melhor compreendimento.

Comment: muito bom obrigado amigo pela dica e otima explicação. Melhor resposta. Sou iniciante também rsrs